# Set analysis formula in table does not work properly

Tags: qlikview, set-analysis

I have a table with formulas using set analysis syntax. Like so:

```
((RAWP_PRICE-ONLY({1<RAWP_YEARMONTH='$(Auswahlperiode)'}>}RAWP_PRICE))*ARRO_AnteilROAR_in_%/100)
/Sum({$<ARRO_PREISPERIODE={'$(Auswahlperiode)'}>}ARRO_ArtikelRohstoffPreis_MONTH)
```

My problem is now, that without the **1** inside the only expression, my table will show now results just "-" signs. But with the **1**, my selcetion does not play a role anymore. But this is important.

How can get this formula running without having my selection ignored. Thanks a lot.

BTW: $(Auswahlperiode) is a variable given in a inputbox.

Comment: you're missing a "{" before '$(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use **1** and still not having selections ignored, depends on how many fields you have, you can use explicit selections inside the set analysis:

for example if I want not to ignore the "Month" field then in the set analysis I will add `Month=$::Month` - so even though I'm using **1**, Month field is not ignored.